# Improving SQL query performance for multi-column grouped aggregation

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to speed up the query performance I'm having for quite a large aggregation. The overall result is to get a number of rankings for some particular categories. The table is simply made up of purchases data, 1-purchase per row e.g.:

```
transactions:
| id | category | netvalue | store_id | suburb | city | country |
|  1 | clothes  |       20 | 12       |    A   | AUCK |    NZ   |
|  2 | food     |       10 | 11       |    B   | WELL |    NZ   |
|  3 | gear     |      120 | 15       |    A   | CHCH |    NZ   |
|  4 | clothes  |       15 |  9       |    C   | SYDN |    AU   |
```

I'd like to get a list of all categories for a particular store, then it's rankings compared to every other store in its own *suburb*, *city* and *country*. For example, store 12 corresponds to:

- *suburb*: A
- *city*: AUCK
- *country*: NZ

I'm trying to generate a result set that looks like:

```
| category | suburb_rank | city_rank | country_rank |
| clothes  | 23          | 20        | 250          |
| food     | 27          | 10        | 109          |
...
```

I thought I'd start off with a set of aggregations, grouped by every *ranking field* that I'm interested in. This results in a query like:

```
WITH aggregations AS (
    SELECT
        category,
        SUM(netvalue) AS sum_netvalue,
        store_id,
        suburb,
        city,
        country
    FROM
        transactions
    GROUP BY
        store_id,
        suburb,
        city,
        country,
        category
)
SELECT * FROM aggregations
```

I'm then using this aggregations table to create rankings for each *ranking column*:

```
WITH aggregations AS (...),
WITH suburb_rankings AS (
    row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY aggregations.category,
        ORDER BY sum(sum_netvalue) DESC
    ) AS rank,
    category,
    store_id
FROM
    aggregations
WHERE
    suburb = @MY_SUBURB
GROUP BY
    category,
    store_id
),
WITH city_rankings AS (...),
WITH country_rankings AS (...)
```

Finally, I'm joining each of these rankings tables to a list of categories to get the category, then ranking for (suburb, city, country):

```
...
SELECT 
    category,
    suburb_rankings.rank AS suburb_rank,
    city_rankings.rank AS city_rank,
    country_rankings.rank AS country_rank
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM transactions)
LEFT JOIN
    suburb_rankings
ON
    suburb_rankings.category = category AND suburb_rankings.store_id = @MY_STORE_ID
LEFT JOIN
    city_rankings
ON
    city_rankings.category = category AND city_rankings.store_id = @MY_STORE_ID        
LEFT JOIN
    country_rankings
ON
    country_rankings.category = category AND country_rankings.store_id = @MY_STORE_ID
```

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, performance wise - and I notice that an EXPLAIN ANALYZE describes a lot of time is spent doing the aggregations.

What I'd like to know is, is there a better approach to this type of query? I can't create a table of pre-computed aggregations because there may be more columns in the original table that we may want to filter on later.

I'm using Postgres 9.2 and SQLAlchemy, and had a brief look at dogpile caching but wasn't too sure if that would be a good solution.

Comment: Looks like you are not interested in store_id. Why is it in the aggregation CTE? Why didn't you group by category in the aggregation CTE?

Comment: Oops that was a typo, category should be in the group by clause. Also, I am interested in the store_id, but not until the final view is created. I think if I don't group by store_id in the aggregations table, I won't be able to tell which aggregations are for what store_id later on? In the final view, I want to filter out the rankings for 1 particular store.